# Excel Formula which will add either this year, or next year to a fixed date (e.g. 1st October), dependent upon whether that date has passed this year?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I understand if I want to enter a fixed date and use the current year I can use the following formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 10, 1)
```

But after the 1st October this year I want the formula to be for next year instead:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1, 10, 1)
```

How can I automate this in excel so that I don't have to manually amend this when the 1st October passes? I need to avoid referencing any other date cells in my spreadsheet.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: `if(today()>date(2022,10,1)...`?

Answer (score 1):

use a boolean to either add 1 or 0:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+(TODAY()>DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 10, 1)), 10, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: @ProductManager please remember after the question is 15 minutes old to check as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(MONTH(A1)<10,DATE(YEAR(A1),10,1),DATE(YEAR(A1)+1,10,1))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).